# Simple explanation of how modulo operations can assign EC2 instances to subnets when using Terraform's AWS Provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

No example code; I am too dumb to understand this section of the [docs](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/count#scale-ec2-configuration-with-count):

> Each instance provisioned by the resource block with `count` will have a different incrementing value for `count.index` - starting with zero. This configuration uses `count.index` and modulo division to assign each instance to a private subnet.

Which refers to this block of code changes:

```
 resource "aws_instance" "app" {
 +  count = var.instances_per_subnet * length(module.vpc.private_subnets)
 +   
    ami           = data.aws_ami.amazon_linux.id   instance_type = var.instance_type
-  subnet_id              = module.vpc.private_subnets[0]
+  subnet_id              = module.vpc.private_subnets[count.index % length(module.vpc.private_subnets)]   vpc_security_group_ids = [module.app_security_group.this_security_group_id]
   ## ...
 }
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on here, or point me to docs that do?

Comment: What is the actual TF code?

Comment: Yep, can you please add your terraform config :)

Comment: Alternatively the `count` meta-argument has been deprecated for a long time so just do not use it.

Comment: @MattSchuchard `count` is definitely not deprecated. They added `for_each` which provides a somewhat different iteration feature, but it does not replace `count`. That's like saying `for` loops in programming languages should all be deprecated and replaced with `while` loops.

Comment: @Marcin everything referenced is on that tutorial; the quote itself refers to the block of code I've posted with the question.  You can get the entire codebase for the example with `git clone https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-count-foreach.git` and `git checkout tags/count-initial-configuration -b count-initial-configuration`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attempt to explain "what is going on here". Please excuse the verbosity.

The objective is to create N instances and "spread" them evenly among M available subnets.

Assume for this example that there are 3 private subnets (say one per Availability Zone).  That is length(module.vpc.private_subnets) has value 3.
The subnet ids of these 3 subnets will be accessible from an array returned by the vpc module as:

- module.vpc.private_subnets[0]
- module.vpc.private_subnets[1]
- module.vpc.private_subnets[2]

Lets assume that you want to create 2 instances per subnet.  That is the variable var.instances_per_subnet has value 2.

The count value for the first expression in the resource block will then be  2 * 3 = 6

The resource block will then create 6 instances.

I like to imagine Terraform "iterating" count.index from 0 to 5 as it creates the 6 instances  (that's just for my understanding; in general you don't really care how it actually happens since HCL is declarative )

Below I try to expand the expression

`subnet_id = module.vpc.private_subnets[count.index % length(module.vpc.private_subnets)]`

for each of the 6 instances created:

Note: In HCL, the modulo operator (%) works roughly like  the [python % operator](https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/).

- For the instance associated with count.index = 0  the subnet id will be module.vpc.private_subnets[0 % 3],  that is we will use the subnet-id given by `module.vpc.private_subnets[0]`
- For count.index = 1 => module.vpc.private_subnets[1 % 3],  that is  `subnet_id = module.vpc.private_subnets[1]`
- For count.index = 2 => module.vpc.private_subnets[2 % 3],  that is  `subnet_id = module.vpc.private_subnets[2]`
- For count.index = 3 we are back to the first subnet since 3 % 3 = 0 =>  `subnet_id = module.vpc.private_subnets[0]`
- For count.index = 4 => module.vpc.private_subnets[4 % 3],  that is  `subnet_id = module.vpc.private_subnets[1]`
- For count.index = 5 => module.vpc.private_subnets[5 % 3],  that is  `subnet_id = module.vpc.private_subnets[2]`

The net result is that we are dividing "evenly" the 6 created instances [0,1,...,5] among the 3 available subnets [0,1,2]